# How to display the last update time in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show the last updated (modified) time in my website. How can I do it in html. This is my script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
This is last updated time

<body onload="myFunction()">
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.lastModified;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's unclear if you are asking how to do this *without JS* or if you want to know why this code isn't working (in which case the error message in the content should be a big clue). What element are you trying to get by its ID?

Comment: It also appears, that `document.lastModified` returns only the current date and time when retrieved on a web page.

Comment: Your html is not well formed, so your question is really weird.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the date object and then use ISOString method,the use substr to get the time from the string

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.lastModified;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new Date(document.lastModified).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
}

myFunction()
```

```html
This is last updated time <span id='demo'></span>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using WordPress. I think your method can use in workpress. Do you know how to insert the function `myfunction` to the page

Comment: you can put inside script tag & try

Comment: Hi, I tried it. But the page only allows to insert text. I added the below code but it shows the text code in the page. ```<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.lastModified;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new Date(document.lastModified).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
}

myFunction()
</script>```

Answer (score 1):

First you have 2 bodys, dont want that.. then you just need to add the `#demo` element to select and innerHTML the lastModified value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  This is last updated time <span id="demo"></span>
  
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.lastModified;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Requested, All you needed was a div element with id "demo"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        function loadTime() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.lastModified;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadTime();">
    <div id="demo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```